# Constraining a specialised class template parameter to integer and floating point

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create class specialisations where one specialisation is for
all integer types, another for all floating point types, another for bool, and
all others for my own types, and to fail to compile with anything else.

I would like integer to be for {signed or unsigned} * {short, int, long or long long}.
It is not desirable to include char but I can live with it. Floating point
is for float, double, and long double.

```
struct MyClass { /* ... */ };

template <class x> struct Specialise;

template <> struct Specialise <bool>    { /* ... */ };
template <> struct Specialise <int>     { /* for short, int, long ... */ };
template <> struct Specialise <double>  { /* for float, double, long double */ };
template <> struct Specialise <MyClass> { /* ... */ };
```

I've tried playing around with variations of:-

```
template <typename x,typename=typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<x>::value,x>::type>
```

but the compiler is telling me I keep getting it wrong. What is the correct syntax please?

(I'm using C++14, but just might be able to upgrade to 17. No chance of experimental 20.)

Comment: And what does the compiler say exactly?

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class specialization. It is possible to use enable_if for it, the example is below. This is C++17 version, for C++14 just replace `_v` with `::value`.

Special check is required for bool since is_integral_v returns true for bool as well.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct MyClass { /* ... */ };

template <class x, class Enable=void> 
struct Specialise;

template <class T> 
struct Specialise<T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_same_v<T, bool>>> 
{ /* for bool */ };

template <class T> 
struct Specialise<T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<T, bool>>>     
{ /* for short, int, long ... */ };

template <class T> 
struct Specialise<T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>    
{ /* for float, double, long double */ };

template <class T> 
struct Specialise<T, typename std::is_same<T,MyClass>>
{ /* for MyClass */ };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define partial specialization for integer types and float-pointing types like

```
// primary template
template <typename x, typename = void> 
struct Specialise;

// partial specialization for integer types
template <typename x>
struct Specialise <x, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<x>::value>::type> {}

// partial specialization for float-pointer types
template <typename x>
struct Specialise <x, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<x>::value>::type> {}
```

And define full specialization for `bool` and `MyClass` as you showed; they're in preference to partial specialization when given the exact same type.